# How to add multipal notes to Microsoft Project 2013

Tags: ms-project

I have a column containing text of comments in an excel file.
each line corespond to a task in my project file with the same order
and i want to put those comments as notes into the project file.
I can of course do it manually
But since there are many lines, how can i quickly accomplish this task?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

If they are in exactly the same order you can do this a couple of ways.

First - insert the Notes column in MS Project then copy from Excel & Paste into MS Project as you would in Excel

Second - insert one of the Text columns, there are 30 of them available in MS Project. Then do the same copy paste.

To insert columns:

- Right click on the column header to the right of where you want the
  column to be.
- From the menu click on Insert Columns
- Pick the column you want to insert

If you are missing the summary tasks in Excel then do this:

- Insert the column called Summary
- Turn on the autofilters (View > Filter drop down > Display Auto Filters)
- Filter for "No"

Note: Once you do this, you'll eventually need to change things in bulk. I often insert a 2nd text column, then copy one into the next as a back up.

Hope that helps.